# update excel files via python

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas

I want to read an excel file, sort the rows , remove duplicate files and re-save the file again

To do that, i have written this script:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.ExcelFile('FILE_NAME.xlsx')
df = data.parse('data')
df.sort_index()
df.drop_duplicates(subset = 'MAKAT', keep='first', inplace=False)
data.close()
print(pd.read_excel(data))
print('**** DONE ****')
```

in the result, I see the rows on the screen but the file stays with the duplicated rows.

My question is how to save these changes to the same file ?

Answer (score 0):

Change the two lines as below:

```
df = df.sort_index()
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset = 'MAKAT', keep='first').sort_values(by=['MAKAT'])
df.to_csv('outputfile.csv)
```

Comment: It doesn't work... the file is still with duplicate rows . i need to remove duplicates, sort by "MAKAT" and save to the same file..